# How can I get raw string when I run a command that includes color from bash script

Tags: python, bash, heroku

I'm running a heroku-cli command as follows:

`heroku run python manage.py my_command -a my_app_id`

It outputs a string, e.g. "abcdefgh".

However, when I run it from a bash script and echo the output to a file:

`` var=`heroku run python manage.py my_command -a my_app_id` && echo $var > test.txt ``

the file ends up containing the following:

`^[[?25l^[[?25habcdefgh ^[[?25h`

I'm not quite sure what these extra characters are - possibly color code or reset code?

Any idea how I can get the raw string. I've tried many things.

Comment: Is the output colored when seen in the terminal? It might be color codes that needs to be removed. Usually commands will have an option to disable colors something like: `--color never` or `--color auto`

Comment: Thanks @andlrc. The output of the command is not in colour but there is a coloured spinner as the command executes so it may be a reset code or something like that. Unfortunately, I cant find any way to disable colour with the heroku cli.

Answer (score 1):

The ANSI codes you are seeing seem to consist of octal 33, a square bracket, a question mark, an integer and a letter. You might try something like

```
sed 's/\o33\[\?[0-9]\{2\}[hl]//g'
```

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you kindly for your answer. I've tried a bunch of sed commands that I found in various places but they don't work for me for some reason. Your suggestion doesn't work for me either. I'm using terminal on OSX by the way. How did you work out that it has an octal 33?

Comment: That's what I read in the Wikipedia article. Try running the output through `od`, or something similar, in order to determine the real codes, rather than their printed representation. That should enable you to craft the necessary regexp.